# Cannot get Cairo working on R install on CentOs 5.7

Tags: r, centos, cairo

I am trying to get the Cairo package for R 3.0.1 to work on CentOs 5.7 (yes I know; but it's what I've been given to work with!).  I cannot get R to find Cairo.  I've installed Cairo and Pango and Pixman.  I can 'locate' them.  But When I try to re-install R, I find this in my config long after running ./configure:

r_cv has_cairo=no
r_cv_has_pangocairo=no

What, precisely, is causing them not to be found by configure?  Can anyone shed some light on this, so I can try to fix the problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use latest R 3.0.2 and gcc-4.8.0 can install successful.

http://cran.csiro.au/src/base/R-3/R-3.0.2.tar.gz